# My father had no much money / My father did not have much money

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, negation, determiners

Can both sentences be acceptable?

> (1) My father did not have much money.
>
> (2) My father had no much money.

If one of them is incorrect, what is the grammatical reason why?

Comment: The first sentence is acceptable. The second is not grammatically correct, however if you changed the 'no' for 'not' it would be correct, yet it would sound stilted. I recommend the first, or an alternative such as 'My father had little money'

Answer (score 4):

> 1. My father did not have much money.
> 2. My father had no much money.

The first sentence uses the adverb *not* to negate the verb phrase. For the noun phrase functioning as the Object, it uses the central determiner *much* with the noun *money*. This sentence is perfectly grammatical.

The second sentence uses the word *no* to try to negate the meaning of *much*. However, the word *no* is a central determiner. It is not an adverb and cannot be used to modify the meaning of *much*. It is used to mean *zero* as opposed to a numeric amount:

- I have no chairs.
- I have no money.

The determiner *no* is a central determiner and cannot be used with other central determiners:

- *I have no the chairs. (ungrammatical)
- *I have no some time. (ungrammatical)
- *I have no any money. (ungrammatical)

If we don't mean *zero*, but want to negate determiners such as *much*, we can use the word *not*:

- My father had *not* much money.

This might be a bit awkward but it's perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence "My father had no much money." is grammatically incorrect. Use "My father didn't have much money." instead.

Comment: How about this sentence? There is no much difference between us.

Comment: @NweiMyintMaung Hmm *no**t*** much difference! See my answer :)